# Print elements from JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have to iterate through a json file. I imported into python as a list and print all the unique locality. However, the code I wrote only prints the first few localities and does not iterate through all 538 elements of the list:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file:      
json_file = json_file.readlines()
json_file = dict(map(json.loads, json_file))

for i in range (0, len(json_file)-1):
    unique = json_file[i]['payload']['locality']
    print(unique)
```

instead it still prints only about 30 localities, how can I fix this?

Heres a snippet of my file:

```
{ 'payload': {'existence_full': 1,
  'geo_virtual': '["50.794876|-1.090893|20|within_50m|4"]',
  'latitude': '50.794876',
  'locality': 'Portsmouth',
  '_records_touched': '{"crawl":16,"lssi":0,"polygon_centroid":0,"geocoder":0,"user_submission":0,"tdc":0,"gov":0}',
  'email': 'info.centre@port.ac.uk',
  'existence_ml': 0.9794948816203205,
  'address': 'Winston Churchill Av',
  'longitude': '-1.090893',
  'domain_aggregate': '',
  'name': 'University of Portsmouth',
  'search_tags': ['The University of Portsmouth',
   'The University of Portsmouth Students Union',
   'University House'],
  'admin_region': 'England',
  'existence': 1,
  'post_town': 'Portsmouth',
  'category_labels': [['Community and Government',
    'Education',
    'Colleges and Universities']],
  'region': 'Hampshire',
  'review_count': '1',
  'geocode_level': 'within_50m',
  'tel': '023 9284 8484',
  'placerank': 42,
  'placerank_ml': 69.2774043602657,
  'address_extended': 'Unit 4',
  'category_ids_text_search': '',
  'fax': '023 9284 3122',
  'website': 'http://www.port.ac.uk',
  'status': '1',
  'neighborhood': ['The Waterfront'],
  'geocode_confidence': '20',
  'postcode': 'PO1 2UP',
  'category_ids': [29],
  'country': 'gb',
  '_geocode_quality': '4'},
 'uuid': '297fa2bf-7915-4252-9a55-96a0d44e358e'}
```

Comment: Your file looks like an invalid json file. Does it pass jsonlint.com  for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have not imported the data into a list, but into a dictionary. If you want to import the json into a list here is how you would do:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file:      
    json_array = json.load(json_file)

for item in json_array:
    unique = item['payload']['locality']
    print(unique)
```

You said you wanted to print all the unique localities, but in your code you are printing all localities without checking if they are unique or not.

Comment: Yes but dont forget the indent.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you have duplicate records in your file and when you load the data into a `dict` the keys are colliding causing a portion of them to be dropped. Instead of storing the data in a `dict`, store it in a `list` instead:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file:      
    lines = json_file.readlines()
    records = list(map(json.loads, lines))
```

You should then be able to iterate through `records`:

```
print('There are %d records' % len(records))
for record in records:
    unique = record['payload']['locality']
    print(unique)
```